# AUTOINCREMENT INVOICE NUMBER WITH PREFIX / PHP and SQL

Tags: php, sql, prefix, invoice

I would like to generate an auto increment invoice number using prefix.

Digits: 11
Prefix: B

From: **B0000000001** to **B0000000020**.

Is there a easy way to do this in PHP?

Comment: What have you tried?  str_pad and concatenation should make this pretty simple in php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can do in in php.

```
$index = 11;
$prefix = 'B';
echo sprintf("%s%011s", $prefix, $index);
```

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.